# How to apply Clean Code to R and what are some alternatives specific to R?

Tags: java, r, coding-style

I self-learned R in a really poor way and I’m trying to improve. I’ve read *Clean Code: A Handbook of Agile Software Craftsmanship* by Robert C. Martin (2009), which provides best practices for coding and I found it helpful. However, my capacity to understand it was limited because I have no programming experience besides R so couldn’t understand the jargon (or much of the examples, written in Java). My question is:

1. In the attached image, I’ve listed terms from *Clean Code* that I didn’t understand and made a guess at what the equivalent would be in **R terminology - could you please correct me if I got any of these wrong?** (I did buy the book, but for the purposes of this question, a pdf of *Clean Code* is found here: [Clean Code pdf](https://enos.itcollege.ee/%7Ejpoial/oop/naited/Clean%20Code.pdf))

If I found other books that provide foundational best practices like *Clean Code* does that are written specifically for/with R, it would really help. I use R for data science and I never get very far into a project without creating a total rat's nest; in particular, I struggle with writing concise code, and in knowing when I should start a new script, and how to get separate scripts to work together coherently.

I have also read Good Enough Practices for Scientific Computing by Wilson et al. (2017), which is great. I do use R projects. Thank you for your time!

[image: Clean Code terminology and my attempt at applying it to R]

Comment: Read https://data-flair.training/blogs/object-oriented-programming-in-r/ and you will get a better idea of how Clean Code /  OOP relates to R concepts.  Whether it is relevant is a matter of opinion.  (And the relevance depends on what kinds of projects you develop in R ...)

Comment: This question will almost certainly get closed, because asking for recommendations is considered off-topic on SO (since there is no way to provide an objective answer). However, my personal recommendations would be [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/), [R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/), and [Fundamentals of Data Vizualization](https://serialmentor.com/dataviz/).

Comment: *"I am not creating software.  So is this the wrong book for me?"* - Umm.  Anytime that you are write R code, you are (in a sense) writing software.  That's not really the issue.  The issue is whether you want or need the R code that you write to be useful / readable / reviewable at some point in the future or by someone other than yourself.  And the answer to that is that if you are doing real science, then you **should** want that, because peer review and reproducibility are a fundamental part of the Scientific Process.

Comment: So textbooks on writing good software are in principle relevant to anyone doing any form of computational science.  That is not to say that "Clean Code" is particularly relevant.  (Just that it is not irrelevant on principle.)  Many of the things that "Software Engineering" oriented textbooks and methodologies talk about are not very relevant to small scale software projects.  For example, Agile is good for projects with codebases of thousands to hundreds of thousands of lines of code, involving multiple developers.  But these things are not entirely irrelevant for tiny projects either.

Comment: Your table doesn't contain the word "function". The two most important concepts for good clean R code are functional programming and vectorization. Follow a style guide on top of that. If you have big projects, create a package with documentation and definitely use git.

Comment: These are all excellent. At first I did think any code could be software, but towards the second part of the book as my comprehension fell off a cliff, I started to wonder whether what Uncle Bob does and what I do are two different things. Realizing that the scale is where the difference lies is what I really needed, thank you Stephen C. Of course I want reproducibility; I also like the part in the book about "the most important collaborator is your future self." Good point Roland, I should have included functions. I didn't because it was one piece I unquestionably understood. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R is a **multi-paradigm language**, so directly adapting OOL-like code style to improve your R skills isn't exactly the best idea. [16 of the usual GoF design patterns are irrelevant or trivial in FP](https://www.norvig.com/design-patterns/) (hence also in R) - it would be more than counterproductive to limit yourself with the OO mindset.

I do recommend reading "Clean Code" (the cosmetics of OO code isn't much different than what FP programmers would consider "clean"), but to really optimize your R code you need a supplement of FP. In that case, plenty of books are available for you to read: Michelson's "An Introduction to Functional Programming Through Lambda Calculus" (if you are completely new to FP), "Functional Thinking" by Neal Ford, "Becoming Functional" by Joshua Backfield.

FP is pure untapped power which you can use in R. Why limit yourself only with OOP?